# Maven jar with classpath in manifest

Tags: maven, jar, manifest.mf

I am making an extra jar containing the project jar and all dependencies, as part of my maven build (with maven-assembly-plugin):

In assembly XML file:

```
    <dependencySet>
        <unpack>false</unpack>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
        <useProjectArtifact>false</useProjectArtifact>
        <outputDirectory>lib</outputDirectory>
    </dependencySet>
```

In POM:

```
<archive>
  <manifest>
     <mainClass>dk.intelligentsystems.platform.deploy.Deployer</mainClass>
     <addDefaultImplementationEntries>true</addDefaultImplementationEntries>
     <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
     <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
   </manifest>
 </archive>
```

The jar contains the correct files, but the dependencies are not being added to the manufest Classpath attribute. How can I make that happen?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of maven-assembly-plugin, I use [maven-shade-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/) in combination with [maven-jar-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/examples/manifest-customization.html) for the same purpose.

```
       <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>shade</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <createDependencyReducedPom>false</createDependencyReducedPom>
                        <filters>
                            <filter>
                                <artifact>*:*</artifact>
                                <excludes>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.SF</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.DSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>META-INF/*.RSA</exclude>
                                    <exclude>.settings/**</exclude>
                                    <exclude>*.classpath</exclude>
                                    <exclude>*.project</exclude>
                                    <exclude>*.txt</exclude>
                                </excludes>
                            </filter>
                        </filters>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Comment: It doesn't look like this does, what I am seeking. But it could be a useful plan B, perhaps.